# Usage of Mysql in offline internet state

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a self-made customer system in PHP running with a **local mySQL Database**.

Now i have a second computer on a different location which has to use this Database too. So i gave this mysql Database on a Server reachable through internet.

My problem is now, that the first one has often **problems with the internet connection** and then the program will not work. **But it has to work every time!**

Now i do not know how i should handle this problem?

- A local Database and one in the internet, but how should i merge them?
- Should i make a local DB per computer and match them together in one?
- I also want to change the framework behind this system to [symfony2](http://symfony.com/) so is there a way to solve this problem with this framework (e.g. [doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/index.html)?)

Thanks for your help!

Update:
My limitation is the Internet connection on the first computer which could not be eliminated.

Comment: -2 because of? Please give me feedback if you do not like the question! Thanks

Comment: 100% uptime require multiple redundancy, and even then is very hard to achieve. If you cant have any down time you need multiple dbs in sync in multiple locations.

Comment: if both computers are on the same LAN, you can have MySQL listen in the local address and connect to it from the other server... take into account that you will need to enable your mysql user to connect from the other server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really have limitations of (1) not being able to move the database off of the machine with a bad connection and (2) not being able to fix the bad connection; you are going to have to keep some sort of local instance on the second machine.

I would try to setup master-master replication from the first machine with the bad connection to the second machine. I'm not sure how reliable this will be considering the replication will be failing often due to the first machine's bad connection. This problem may be extrapolated if one or both machines are using old versions of MySQL. MySQL 5.5, for example, can be configured to [actively monitor replication connectivity](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/12/29/actively-monitoring-replication-connectivity-with-mysqls-heartbeat/).

If the majority of your application does READS instead of WRITES, perhaps you could install Memcached (or something similar) on the second machine so that the application can pull data from local memory without requiring a connection to the MySQL server.

Comment: i'll test this. Sounds the way i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve what you want (although maybe not exactly how you described), but the best way is definitely do host the database on a server that doesn't have Internet connectivity problems. Look for hosting that allows remote MySQL connections.

Comment: 1) DB on a computer without problems 2) Computer with problems can't establish connection to that db -> Computer with problems can not run program -> that is what should not happen and will happen in your case if i did understand you. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Yes, the computer with the connectivity problems would have problems in that case, but at least it won't affect the actual application. You can sync the MySQL databases to achieve the result you want, but IMO it's overkill for something like this. Still, check out: http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ (sync software)